# Update column of a table depending of other entries in this table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, self-join

I want to update a column of a table depending on other entries in this table and a join to another table.

What I have (simplified):

A base table

```
id V
1  2
2  3
```

Another table with several million entries that look like this:

```
id A B C D ...
1  1 1 1 a
2  1 1 2 b
3  1 2 1 a
4  1 2 2 b
5  2 1 1 b
6  2 1 2 b
7  2 2 1 a
8  2 2 2 b
9  2 3 1 b
10 2 3 2 b

A -> id from basetable
B -> number from basetable.V
C -> a number
D -> some text
```

I want to:

```
UPDATE row2.D 
WHERE row1.A = row2.B AND row1.A = row2.B AND row1.C = 1 AND row2.C = 2 AND row1.D == row2.D
JOIN basetable ON basetable.id = A AND basetable.V = B
```

In this example it should only affect row 10

I have tried several JOINs but I cant figure it out how to do it

Comment: What would be expected output ?

Comment: row1.A = row2.B AND row1.A = row2.B. What about where row1.A = row2.B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:
Note that This script is `select` version. You can simply use this as update

```
Select table as row1 inner join table as row2 on row1.A = row2.B
INNER join basetable...
Where row1.C =1 and row2.C = 2 And row1.D = row2.D
```

.

Comment: Thank you it worked (with little modification)! This is the final Update SQL:

`UPDATE table as row2
INNER join table as row1 on row1.A = row2.A AND row1.B = row2.B AND row1.id != row2.id 
INNER join basetable ON basetable.id=row1.A AND basetable.V=row1.B 
SET row2.D=''
WHERE row1.C=1 and row2.C=2 AND REGEXP_REPLACE(row1.D, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '') LIKE  REGEXP_REPLACE(row2.D, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '')`